# Restoring Incremental backups in Oracle 10g

Tags: oracle

In our application, we are planning to go for Incremental Backup due to the excess time it takes. Now we have two dump files:one is full backup and the other is incremental backup since the previous full or incremental backup.My problem is i need to merge these two dump files to get the latest data which i can then import. But i am not able to get how to merge these two backups(full backup and incremental backup).I have read about RMAN but did not get clear idea on the syntax of Restore command in RMAN.Please help me on this soon.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly what do you mean when you say you have an "incremental backup"?

You talk about having "two dump files" which implies that you have the output of two different calls to the export utility.  Potentially, the second export call could have used the INCTYPE parameter.  That is not what most people would mean when they talk about a backup or an incremental backup.  An incremental export will do a complete export of every table where any data changed between the last export and the "incremental" export.  That is almost never what people want (or think they're getting) from an incremental export.  If you have the output of two calls to the export utility, there is no way to merge them.  You'd need to import the full export and then the incremental export (which would completely re-load all the data in most if not all of the tables).  And dump files cannot be used with the RMAN utility.

When you talk about your "two dump files", it's also possible, I suppose, that you are referring to an actual RMAN full backup and a RMAN incremental backup.  That would almost certainly involve more than two files and wouldn't normally be called a "dump file" but you would at least be able to restore the backups using RMAN.  Can you post the RMAN backup command you used to create the backups (if you did, indeed, create physical backups using RMAN)?